# Magento & Wordpress Pretty Permalinks Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I have Magento installed on the root of my server.

I have Wordpress 4.0.1 installed on a sub-folder /blog

With permalinks set to default e.g. ?p=123 posts load correctly

With permalinks set to post name e.g. /blog/%postname%/ I get the 404 error from the Magento store

I've attempted to introduce an .htaccess file into the /blog folder with some settings in it, however as yet, I'm unable to set pretty permalinks and get the relevant post page to appear.

Any suggestions on what needs to be in the .htaccess file or howelse to resolve this issue?

Comment: what permission set for /Blog folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have following code in .htaccess which is in folder /Blog :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Added, still no change.

Folder properties are 755

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work - i'm starting to think there is an overriding URL rule in Magento (on the root of the site) causing the issue.

Magento question: should there be a .htaccess file in the root folder of Magento?